How do I share my custom snippets with others in JupyterLab version 4.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?

Do you find yourself typing in the same code blocks over and over again? Are you tired of clicking through tabs online for starter code or browsing old notebook files to find the right import statements? Save, reuse, and share code snippets using JupyterLab Code Snippets! In the past, you would spend more time scouring the internet than actually working. Searching old code for snippets is like searching for your lost keys; it’s frustrating! 
Source


The code snippet extension currently doesn't provide any import or export capabilities. However, you can access the relevant metadata files that contain the definitions.
The definitions are stored in the $JUPYTER_DATA_DIR/metadata/code-snippets directory, where $JUPYTER_DATA_DIR refers to the Jupyter data directory, which you can identify by running the following command in a terminal window:
$ jupyter --data-dir 
Source

I am running JupyterLab version 4.0 using the command jupyter lab. I am sharing public JupyterLab access with others. I have tried to use Google Drive to share the custom snippets thinking that Google Drive is a good source of collaboration, but I do not know how to connect JupyterLab with Google Drive.
How do I share my custom snippets with others in JupyterLab version 4.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?

Note the pattern in OP's questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/768327/revisions https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/758306/revisions https://askubuntu.com/posts/1523955/revisions - the second edit in all of them being just unnecessary whitespace, the zero attempts at trying anything, the massive revisions that completely change the question. I wonder how many revisions this post will remain in the same question.

Which version of Ubuntu? Which version of JupyterLab? How is JupyterLab being run? How are you sharing JupyterLab access with others? And what have you tried? You link to something, did you try using that? Which version of that?

Like pulling teeth indeed ... "How is JupyterLab being run? How are you sharing JupyterLab access with others? And what have you tried? You link to something, did you try using that? Which version of that?" And why did you change the quoted text - why is this quote better for the question than the previous one? Are you running an ad for this thing?

So you have no access controls on JupyterLab at all? Then simply sharing the URL of JupyterLab like you do now will let others see these snippets just like you do. If not, your newly quoted text tells you where the snippets are, just copy-paste them to wherever you want to share. Note that the second quoted text is from 2021, so probably out-of-date, so again, what have you tried? Just quoting some text from some site isn't trying anything

Voting to close the question because it lacks vital information as described here

"You link to something, did you try using that? Which version of that?" "And why did you change the quoted text - why is this quote better for the question than the previous one? Are you running an ad for this thing?" And now: what happened when you tried using Google Drive? Why did you use Google Drive when you're linking to some JupyterLab plugin?

DO NOT use flags to indicate an answer needs attention.  That's what Bounties are for, and Moderators do not have the power to influence anything.

@muru The bounty is almost expiring. Waiting for an answer to this question.

According to the documentation at least real time collaboration is possible using the extension jupyter-collaboration (starting from JupyterLab v4). Note that this is only for collaboration not for sharing a notebook per se.
Just sharing doesn't seem to be intended. You might want to take a look at this thread. According to there, there is no perfect solution.
In short:
Either use jupyter-collaboration which doesn't do sharing, just collaboration, use Github or any other git system (this is what I'd recommend) or use Google Colab which is user friendly option for some use cases but unlikely to be compatible with your needs.
Your "code snippets" use case might require a different approach although I'd still recommend Github.
